# Query rows that have same column value and return one result for each duplicate

Tags: mysql

I am using this query to return duplicate email addresses in a table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `customers` 
WHERE email IN ( SELECT email FROM `customers` GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(id) > 1)
```

Sample Output:

```
TonyLoden - tloden@outlook.com
TonyLoden - tloden@outlook.com
MikeH3llgarth - mike.hallgarth@gmail.com
MikeH3llgarth - mike.hallgarth@gmail.com
```

How can I modify the query to return only ONE result for each duplicate found?

Meaning, instead I would like it to return:

```
TonyLoden - tloden@outlook.com
MikeH3llgarth - mike.hallgarth@gmail.com
```

Comment: I think DISTINCT clause could solve your problem.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...` OR add `GROUP BY email` as the last statement

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic.

Comment: I used "SELECT DISTINCT" and it output the same as the original. The primay key is "id"

Comment: if you use `DISTINCT *`, it will see each record (with a unique primary key)  as being an individual record (rightly).  You could do `SELECT DISTINCT(email)...`